# Laravel Livewire: Radio button not properly working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In the applications, there are 2 tabs:

1. Personal Details
2. Interview Questions

In the interview questions, it is a setup coming from configurations and there is a radio button "Yes" or "No"

[image]

In this example,

In question # 1, I choose "Yes" but the value changed in question # 3 not in the question # 1.

Below is my code for  in getting the interview questions

**Controller**

```
public $interivew_questions = [];
public $answers = [];

$interview_questions                = InterviewQuestions::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                                                        ->where('active',1)
                                                        ->get();

        foreach ($interview_questions as $i_q => $interview_question) {
            # code...
            $this->interview_questions[] = 
            [
                'remarks' => $interview_question->remarks,
                'answer' => "",
            ];
        }
```

**View**

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
@foreach($interview_questions as $i_q => $interview_question)
    <?php $counter++; ?>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <span style="font-weight: bolder; display: inline;">{{ $counter }}.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
             <p wire:model="interview_questions.{{$i_q}}.remarks"> {{ $interview_question['remarks'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 offset-md-1 offset-xs-1 offset-sm-1 offset-lg-1">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" wire:model="answers" name="answers" value="YES" /> YES
                <!-- <input type="radio" wire:model="interview_questions.{{$i_q}}.answer" name="answers" value="YES" /> YES -->
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" wire:model="answers" name="answers" value="NO" /> NO
                <!-- <input type="radio" wire:model="interview_questions.{{$i_q}}.answer" name="answers" value="NO" /> NO -->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**UPDATED POST**

I removed the name in my input field, it is now getting the correct answer in corresponding questions but it can now check both "Yes" or "No"

Question: How do I get the correct answer for corresponding question #?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the commented out inputs instead? I'm not familiar with livewire but I can guess it is an input id issue here.

Comment: I already tried that but it is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply using the wrong `wire:model`. Livewire tries to be smart. Since your property is an array, Livewire considers it multiple choice. When using the correct syntax, Livewire will handle the selection and deselection of radio and checkbox types.

Your commented input has the correct syntax but simply points to the wrong property.

```html
<input type="radio" wire:model="answers.{{$i_q}}.answer" value="YES"/>
<input type="radio" wire:model="answers.{{$i_q}}.answer" value="NO"/>
```

P.S. you should *never* use `name` attribute when using Livewire. It's simply unnnecessary.